# Wifi adapter not found HP 15-db0008ca

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, realtek-wireless

I'm helping my friend install Ubuntu on his new laptop and we're having trouble getting it to see the wireless adapter. I tried a few fixes I found on here but nothing has worked yet. His laptop is an HP 15-db0008ca and the wireless card is a  Realtek RTL8821CE.

Thanks in advance.

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:831a]
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Done, I'll copy it again here for reference. Thanks again in advance.

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:831a]
2: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: So, this didn't quite work. At the last step I got the response: 'modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8821ce' : Required key not available'